# How to decode "Ð¡Ð²ÐµÑ€Ð´..." data format (name of region in Russia) in .csv file to English in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, decode, decoding, string-decoding

I am working on a project on Machine learning. When I download the .csv file, some of the features have values in an unknown format. Something like `Ð¡Ð²ÐµÑ€Ð´Ð»Ð¾Ð²ÑÐºÐ°Ñ Ð¾Ð±Ð»Ð°ÑÑ‚ÑŒ` and `Ð›Ð¸Ñ‡Ð½Ñ‹Ðµ Ð²ÐµÑ‰Ð`. These represent the names of regions in Russia. Can anyone tell me how to convert them into plane English in R? I tried doing the following:

```
df <- read.csv(file.choose(), sep = ',', header = TRUE, encoding = "russian", 
stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Doesn't work

Sample of data:

```
| region | City |
|---|---|
| ÐÐ¸Ð¶ÐµÐ³Ð¾Ñ€Ð¾Ð´ÑÐºÐ°Ñ Ð¾Ð±Ð»Ð°ÑÑ‚ÑŒ | ÐšÑ€Ð°ÑÐ½Ð¾Ð´Ð°Ñ€ |
| Ð’Ð¾Ñ€Ð¾Ð½ÐµÐ¶ÑÐºÐ°Ñ Ð¾Ð±Ð»Ð°ÑÑ‚ÑŒ | Ð§ÐµÐ»ÑÐ±Ð¸Ð½ÑÐº |
| ÐÐ¸Ð¶ÐµÐ³Ð¾Ñ€Ð¾Ð´ÑÐºÐ°Ñ Ð¾Ð±Ð»Ð°ÑÑ‚ÑŒ | Ð’Ð¾Ñ€Ð¾Ð½ÐµÐ¶ |
| ÐÐ¸Ð¶ÐµÐ³Ð¾Ñ€Ð¾Ð´ÑÐºÐ°Ñ Ð¾Ð±Ð»Ð°ÑÑ‚ÑŒ | ÐšÑ€Ð°ÑÐ½Ð¾Ð´Ð°Ñ€ |
| ÐšÑ€Ð°ÑÐ½Ð¾ÑÑ€ÑÐºÐ¸Ð¹ ÐºÑ€Ð°Ð¹ | Ð¡Ð°Ð¼Ð°Ñ€Ð° |
| Ð Ð¾ÑÑ‚Ð¾Ð²ÑÐºÐ°Ñ Ð¾Ð±Ð»Ð°ÑÑ‚ÑŒ | Ð¢ÑŽÐ¼ÐµÐ½ÑŒ |
```

Comment: Can you share a small sample of the CSV so we can confirm the solution work before posting an answer? Thanks.

Comment: Try `encoding = "UTF-8"`?

Comment: @onlyphantom I added a small portion of the data and @Mako212, I tried switching "russian" with "UTF-8", it didn't work, instead, my data set initially had a million instances and it returned only 80k. Also the format of these values in now something like `<U+041D><U+0438><U+0436><U+0435><U+0433>`. Not sure if that means something